# Don't know what pattern and matcher does

Tags: java, case-insensitive, matcher

Hi this is part of an example question..I would like to know what exactly this code does.

```
 if (Pattern.compile(".*" + search + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(one).matches());
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: thanks ill go through those now as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Basically, the code is the check that content of a `search` variable is contained in the text of `one` variable.

`.*` means 'any character' (`.`) 'zero or more times' (`*`), So the pattern is `search` surrounded by any number of any characters.